# How can one name a TikZ \graph and position a \node below it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I'd like to place a node below a `\graph` in a `tikzpicture`. But, for some reason, I can't access the `\graph`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,graphs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [name=graph] {a -> b};
    \node[below of=graph] {$t_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in: `Package pgf Error: No shape named graph is known. ^^I\node[below of=graph] {$t_1$};`

`\graph (name) {...};` leads to `File ended while scanning use of \tikz@lib@graph@node@naked.`

`\graph {a -> b} node[below] {$t_1$};` works but the label `$t_1$` appears below the node `a`. Can I shift it to the centre?

(I'd prefer to use the `graphs` library and not `graphdrawing`, since the latter requires LuaLaTeX)

Comment: There is also (current bounding box) to position nodes relative to.

Comment: @JohnKormylo of course! `\node[below of=current bounding box] {$t_1$};` works perfectly. Would you like to turn that into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Nah.  Don't really need the points.  AFAICT, there are no more superpowers to be gained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `local bounding box`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,graphs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=graph]
     \graph  {a -> b};
    \end{scope} 
    \node[below=1ex of graph] {$t_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can consider the graph as a whole like a big node (edit: [Schrödinger's cat's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530116/73317) does exactly that), but you can certainly name individual nodes of the graph and reference them in the rest of the `tikzpicture`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, graphs, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph {a[name=a] -> b[name=b]};
\coordinate (m) at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$); % midpoint between a and b
\node[below=0.5cm of m] {$t_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the use of `below=0.5cm of m` instead of the syntax `below of=...`, which doesn't make use of the `positioning` Ti*k*Z library.

There are other possibilities to tell that some particular node of your graph should be anchored at some particular position of your `tikzpicture`: see `anchor node=`, `anchor here` and `desired at=` in section *Anchoring a Graph* of the [Ti*k*Z & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), around page 425.

Other ways to do the same:

```latex
\graph {a[name=a] -> b[name=b]};
\path (a) -- (b) node[pos=0.5, below=0.5cm] {$t_1$};
```

and

```latex
\graph {a[name=a] -> b[name=b]};
\path (a) -- node[pos=0.5, below=0.5cm] {$t_1$} (b);
```

The Ti*k*Z `calc` library is not needed for these last two techniques.